# TCL Thread: Tracking that a child Tcl Thread is still running

Tags: multithreading, tcl, send

I am facing a problem with determining whether a Tcl thread is still running or not.  I have code that looks like this:

```
package require Thread
proc p1 {} {
    set tid [thread::create {
        #Child Thread
        proc executeCommand {} {  
            #Run several command line commands
            return 1
        }
        thread::wait
    }]
    set currentProcessID [twapi::get_current_process_id]
    set var ::p1results($tid)
    set $var ""

    #Get all threads before ::thread::send
    set beforeThreads [twapi::get_process_thread_ids $currentProcessID]

    ::thread::send -async $tid [list executeCommand {}] $var

    #Get all threads after ::thread::send
    set afterThreads [twapi::get_process_thread_ids $currentProcessID]

    #set processThreadId to be the difference between before and after twapi calls
    set processThreadId {}
    foreach threadId $afterThreads {
        if {[lsearch -exact $beforeThreads $threadId] == -1} {
            set processThreadId $threadId
        }
    }

    while {[lsearch -exact [twapi::get_process_thread_ids $currentProcessID] $processThreadId] > -1} {
        #Notify a database that child thread is still running 
        after 3000
    }

    vwait $var
    set result [set $var]
    unset $var
    ::thread::release $tid
    return $result
}

p1
```

As you can see, I am currently tracking the child thread, that I started with ::thread::send, with the TCL twapi package.  I do not want to block the parent thread with 'vwait' or else I will not be able to notify the DB that the child thread is still running.  This has proven to be unreliable, as occasionally the thread id that I have stored 'processThreadId' will exit before my thread 'proc executeCommand {}' finishes.

So my question is this - is there a reliable way for the parent thread (main thread) to track if a child thread is still running, without blocking the parent thread with 'vwait'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the thread::mutex locks, which are much more reliable than the twapi package I was using before.

Essentially, I create a thread::mutex and grab the lock in the parent thread.  I then thread::send to my worker thread the mutex handle.  The parent thread then loops, attempting to re-lock the mutex and catching/ignoring the "locking the same exclusive mutex twice from the same thread" error message.  The parent thread will break out of the while loop when "thread::mutex lock" does not throw an error.

The worker thread goes through its list of command and calls "thread::mutex unlock" just before the return statement.  I also needed to wrap the "executeCommand" in a catch statement so I could unlock the mutex in case the worker thread gets an unexpected error.

So the mutex being locked represents the worker thread running, once it becomes unlocked it has no more commands to run.

```
package require Thread
proc p1 {} {
    set mutexHand [::thread::mutex create]
    set tid [thread::create {
        proc wrapCommad {mutHand} {
            if {[catch {set data [executeCommand]} err]} {
                thread::mutex unlock $mutHand
                return -code error $err
            }
            thread::mutex unlock $mutHand
            return $data
        }
        proc executeCommand {} {  
            #Run several command line commands
            return 1
        }
        thread::wait
    }]
    set var ::p1results($tid)
    set $var ""
    thread::mutex lock $mutexHand 
    ::thread::send -async $tid [list wrapCommand $mutexHand] $var

    while {1} {
        if {[catch {thread::mutex lock $mutexHand} err] } {
            puts "WORKER STILL RUNNING"
        } else {
            puts "WORKER NOT RUNNING"
            break;
        }
        after 3000
    }

    vwait $var
    thread::mutex unlock $mutexHand
    thread::mutex destroy $mutexHand
    set result [set $var]
    unset $var
    ::thread::release $tid
    return $result
}

p1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the id of the worker thread, you can use [`thread::exists`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/thread.htm#M16) to query if it is still alive. It takes just the id as an argument, and returns a boolean, which should be exactly what you need.

However, the thread could die immediately after you ask the question; no way to prevent that in a true, general async system. I prefer to arrange for the worker thread to send a message back when it is done, and once that message is received I know that everything is finished. I often like to think in terms of sending "work items" to threads, rather than just simple messages.

Comment: The problem with thread::exists is that it will not return false until ::thread::release is called in the parent thread. Putting "thread::exists $tid" in my while will just result in infinite loop.  Is it possible for the worker thread to send a message back to the parent thread without the parent blocking/waiting for the message?

Comment: @Jake Until the release is done, it does indeed exist. You can send messages asynchronously using the `-async` option to `thread::send`; the sender needs the ID of the receiver to do that, of course.

Comment: My question is more, with out the parent thread releasing the worker, and with out the parent thread blocking execution with 'vwait', is there anyway the parent thread can track if the worker thread is still running (worker hasn't returned yet)?